# What happens if a student fails an O.W.L.?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts

Are they allowed to retake the exam? Or would it mean they must repeat the same study year?

Comment: Why remove the [Hogwarts] tag, @Randal'Thor? This seems like a Hogwarts question to me

Comment: @Mith It's a UK question. Presumably home schooled wizards can take the OWLs too

Comment: The owl will screech really angrily and try to claw the student.

Comment: They are just expelled out of Hogwarts...

Comment: Well if the student role-plays a ferret they might be preyed upon by the owl... unless they're rescued, of course.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

> Or would it mean they must repeat the same study year?

Absolutely not. Fred and George for example got only three OWLs each, meaning they failed seven, but they certainly aren't held back:

> 'Anyway, it's a nightmare of a year, the fifth,' said George. 'If you care about exam results, anyway. Fred and I managed to keep our peckers up somehow.'
>
> 'Yeah ... you got, what was it, three OWLs each?' said Ron.
>
> 'Yep,' said Fred unconcernedly. 'But we feel our futures lie outside the world of academic achievement.'
>
> 'We seriously debated whether we were going to bother coming back for our seventh year,' said George brightly, 'now that we've got -'
>
> *Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* - p.205 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 12, *Professor Umbridge*

It only means that their choice of NEWT subject was pretty limited by their poor grades. This we can infer from the fact that Hogwarts teachers set entrance requirements for their classes. Snape, for example, famously required O at OWL for admittance into his NEWT Potions class.

> Are they allowed to retake the exam?

[Mithrandir's fine answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/155419/46027) shows us that they are *allowed* but they certainly don't *have* to. There's no way Fred and George retook seven subjects in *The Goblet of Fire* (the year after their OWL year). Similarly, Harry failed Divination and History of Magic and did not retake them:

> ORDINARY WIZARDING LEVEL RESULTS
>
> Pass Grades: Outstanding (O), Exceeds Expectations (E), Acceptable (A)
>
> Fail Grades: Poor (P), Dreadful (D), Troll (T)
>
> HARRY JAMES POTTER HAS ACHIEVED:
>
> [...]
>
> Divination: P
>
> [...]
>
> History of Magic: D
>
> *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince* - p.100 - Bloomsbury - Chapter 5, *An Excess of Phlegm*

Comment: `Fred and George for example got only three OWLs each, meaning they failed seven, but they certainly aren't held back` One could say they weren't held _[at all](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Fred_and_George_Weasley%27s_departure_from_Hogwarts)_...

Comment: I can almost hear Hermione gnashing her teeth from here, do to Fred and George's attitude...  ;-)  Hope she wasn't nearby when this conversation took place!

Comment: @BaardKopperud She was actually, but she was soon distracted by talk of the joke shop - and it was the Skiving Snackboxes that started the conversation in the first place :P

Comment: The model is almost certainly the same as O-levels, which Rowling will have experienced herself. The practice was that you could retake them but you did not have to.

Comment: To add to that, O-Levels were not an *immediate* retake. You would have to retake either about six months later, or one year later, and usually you would be expected to be at school for that time.

Answer (score 47):

They either have to or can take them again the next year, presumably learning what they were supposed to the previous year, as we see Crabbe and Goyle do:

> "Keep your voice down!" spat Snape, for Malfoy's voice had risen excitedly. "If your friends Crabbe and Goyle intend to pass their Defense Against the Dark Arts OWL this time around, they will need to work a little harder than they are doing at pres-"
>   <sub>*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince*, chapter 15</sub>

Comment: Oh, wow. Nice find!

Comment: Technically this only shows they just have the option to take them again (which is how I and the other answer interpret it).

Comment: @AdamMartin - actually, I interpreted it as being if you fail enough of them you have to retake all of them.

Comment: @Mithrandir why? Fred and George did not even finish school and went on to run a successful business. They neither "had to retake" nor even graduate.

Comment: @Mithrandir: I am pretty sure you are wrong about the compulsion.  JKR and I are both British, and the model in Britain is that you *can* retake, but there is no obligation to.  (IRL, if you fail enough GCSE/O-levels, you wouldn't be able to do A-levels - but they aren't compulsory either.)